# OpenGL ES rotate model in 3 axis

Tags: android, opengl-es, rotation

I'm rotating with model in Android's OpenGL.

Why those two examples below don't produce same results? I thought, there is no difference, when I rotate about axis `x` and then `y` or `y` and then `x`.

```
gl.glRotatef(_angleY, 0f, 1f, 0f); //ROLL
gl.glRotatef(_angleX, 1f, 0f, 0f); //ELEVATION
gl.glRotatef(_angleZ, 0f, 0f, 1f); //AZIMUTH


gl.glRotatef(_angleX, 1f, 0f, 0f); //ELEVATION
gl.glRotatef(_angleY, 0f, 1f, 0f); //ROLL
gl.glRotatef(_angleZ, 0f, 0f, 1f); //AZIMUTH
```

Comment: Congratulations, you just found **one** of the reasons why Euler angles are usually a bad representation for rotations: There is a huge amount of different conventions and **they indeed all give different results** and everybody thinks his convention is standard, though they're all equally (un)powerful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless those rotations are all applied simultaneously, I would think order definitely would matter.

If I had a cube and I rotated it around the **x axis** and moved the **front face** to the **top**, after rotating around the **y axis**, the **original front face** would still be on the **top**.

If instead I first rotated around the **y axis** then the **original front face** would be moved aside so when I then rotated around the **x axis** the **original front face** would **NOT** be rotated to the **top**.

I believe that order of rotation **does** matter.